# Javascript to add the numbers delimited by comma

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the sum of all the integers whithin a text box. The numbers are separated by comma. I need to add the numbers and get their sum.I am not able to get them sadly.

my code is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function computeData()
        {
            var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
            var temp = data.split(",");
            for( i=0; i<temp.length; i++)
            var k=0;
            {
                var j = temp[i];
                k  = k + j;
                alert(k);
            }
            document.getElementById("sum").value= k;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is integer + string an integer or a string? If it's a string, you'll need to specifically convert `j` into an integer first

Comment: What is the input, and what is the result you are getting. I would guess two outcomes, either a concatenated string, or only the last number. If concatentaed string, you need to cast the split string as numbers, or if only the last number it appears as though you are reassigning k  to 0 every for loop ( but bit sure if you just typed it here incorrectly)

Comment: You only need to change one line `k  = k + parseFloat(temp[i]);` Pointless setting j there too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse your strings into integers using `parseInt`:

```
> 2 + '3'
'23'
> 2 + parseInt('3', 10)
5
```

The `10` tells `parseInt` to assume that the number is base-10. If you have floating point numbers, use `parseFloat()` (you don't need to specify a radix):

```
> 2 + parseFloat('3.13')
5.13
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know they'll be integers:

```
var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
var sum = data.split(",").reduce(function(prev, curr){
    return parseInt(prev,10) + parseInt(curr,10);
 });
```

If you aren't sure about integers you can use `parseFloat` in place of the parseInt.

Note that this may not work in older browsers.  If you need to support IE older than IE9, you probably just want to use parseInt/parseFloat in your loop as is. (with the k declaration moved outside the loop)

```
var k=0;
for( i=0; i<temp.length; i++)
{
     var j = temp[i];
     k  = k + parseInt(j,10);
     alert(k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work on a CSV string of integers or floats.

```
var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
var a = data.match(/\d+(?:[.]\d+)?/g);
var num = 0;
a.forEach(function(n){
    num += parseFloat(n);
});

console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might also suggest the following syntax

```
        var temp = data.split(",");
        for(var i=0, k=0; i<temp.length; i++;)
        {
            k += parseInt(temp[i]);
        }
```

Comment: This will fail for strings with syntax like "09,010", and k also needs to be initialized to 0 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
var data = '1,2,3';

eval(data.split(',').join('+'))); // 6
```

or

```
eval(data.replace(/,/g,'+')); // 6
```

#### Edit

For all those eval haters out there (you know who you are!!):

```
var sum = data.split(',').reduce(function(p, c){return p + +c},0);
```

Note that support for [ES5 *reduce*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21) is required, there's a [polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill).

Comment: Ah yes, now I remember… :-)

Comment: @SamratSaha—there you go, a shiny new, non–eval solution. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I like the eval idea, but you can also use a regular expression to match and total the integers and decimals, and any plus or minus signs. Non numbers are ignored, so you can delimit with commas or spaces, or just use '+' or '-' between numbers.

```
function computeData(){
    var data= document.getElementById("data").value;
    var rx=/([+-]?(\.\d+|\d+(\.\d+)?))/g, n= 0, M;
    while((M= rx.exec(data))!= null){
        n+= (+M[1])
    }
    document.getElementById("sum").value= n;
}
```