# How to display sum of the values entered in input box in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display sum of the values entered in front of my label dynamically, it should added automatically, For eg: You can see the below image for reference[This should be the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gGFV.png)

I have set the state, but I am not getting the logic to add the numbers, I have just set the value, you can see the below image
[I have set just the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcFli.png)

Here is my code

```
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, {useState} from "react"
import './App.css';

function App() {
const [first, setfirst] = useState(0)

const addChange=(e)=>{
  setfirst(e.target.value)
  Math.

}
  return (
    <>
    <label>Sum of inputs:{first} <input type="text"  onChange={addChange}></input></label>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please let know, if I need to provide some more details.

Comment: Split the string by comma, parse each value as an integer, and add all the values?

Comment: Please don't use pictures as the only source of information in a post. You can easily describe what those pictures show in words: *If the user enters "10, 4", the sum should be "14"* *In my code, when the user enters "10, 4", the sum shows as "10,4"*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript to add the numbers delimited by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262078/javascript-to-add-the-numbers-delimited-by-comma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can split the value with "," and and find the sum of the array:

```
export default function App() {
const [first, setfirst] = useState(0)

const addChange=(e)=>{
    const sumArr = e.target.value.split(",");
    const sum = sumArr.reduce(function(a, b){
      return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
    }, 0);
    if(sum) {
      setfirst(sum);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
    <label>Sum of inputs:{first} <input type="text" onChange={addChange}></input></label>
    </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-shockley-u4kch8?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the value of your input as a string and do a split (",") to remove each number from the string and parse them to number. After that you have to add each number together to get the sum .

Answer (score -1):

You can use logic of splitting the string and then summing the number up. Since its a free textBox, make sure you add a check for `NaN`

```
const addChange=(e)=>{
  setfirst(e.target.value.split(',').reduce((a, c) => a + (isNaN(+c) ? 0 : +c), 0))
}
```

Comment: it will not work if we don't have "," ???

Comment: The OP is about having a comma, and the answer supports a comma.

Comment: what if user type . instead of ,  it's limited solution in my opinion

Comment: Its not, the OP is not about scalability or robustness, its about fixing a code.

Comment: You're right ^^ in the image : 10,4 = 14 i thaught he is looking for something like that 10.4 = 5

Answer (score -1):

I propose this solution to calculate the sum of number in input (if you type evything else than number between 0 and 10 it will not taked in consideration)

```js
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import './App.css';

function App() {
const [first, setfirst] = useState("");
const [sum, setSum] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
 let sumInput =0;
 for(var i =0; i<first.length; i++) {
   if(!isNaN(first[i])) sumInput = sumInput + parseInt(first[i])
 }
 setSum(sumInput )
}, [first])

  return (
    <>
    <label>Sum of inputs:{sum}  <input type="text" value={first} onChange={(e) => setfirst(e.target.value)} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```